# How to generate token for apple pay integration using authorize.net

Tags: php, authorize.net, applepay

I am trying to integrate apple pay using authorize.net in my php project.
Here is my code,

```
$op = new AnetAPI\OpaqueDataType();
$op->setDataDescriptor("COMMON.APPLE.INAPP.PAYMENT");
$op->setDataValue("XXXX");
```

Here XXXX in the `$op->setDataValue("XXXX");` is token for apple pay.
So anyone can help me how to generate it ?

I have referred official documentation of authorize.net
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#mobile-in-app-transactions
 , but didn't get any useful resources.